# How to use script to connect Random Value node to Extrude Mesh node in geometry node tree?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

The following code create a geometry node tree correctly, but can't create the link between Value and Selection. The the two lines between ######## should have the same effect; either line should produce the required link.

Can anyone please help?

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()
gnTree = bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"]
gn_groupInput = gnTree.nodes["Group Input"]
gn_groupOutput = gnTree.nodes["Group Output"]
gn_subdivideMesh = gnTree.nodes.new(type="GeometryNodeSubdivideMesh")
gn_subdivideMesh.inputs["Level"].default_value = 2
gn_extrudeMesh = gnTree.nodes.new(type="GeometryNodeExtrudeMesh")
gn_randomValue = gnTree.nodes.new(type="FunctionNodeRandomValue")
gn_randomValue.data_type = 'BOOLEAN'
gn_subdivideMesh.location.x = -160
gn_randomValue.location.x = -160
gn_randomValue.location.y = -120
gn_extrudeMesh.location.x = 30    
gnTree.links.new(gn_groupInput.outputs["Geometry"], gn_subdivideMesh.inputs["Mesh"])
gnTree.links.new(gn_subdivideMesh.outputs["Mesh"], gn_extrudeMesh.inputs["Mesh"])
######### 
gnTree.links.new(gn_randomValue.outputs["Value"], gn_extrudeMesh.inputs["Selection"])
gnTree.links.new(gn_randomValue.outputs[0], gn_extrudeMesh.inputs[1])
######### 
gnTree.links.new(gn_extrudeMesh.outputs["Mesh"], gn_groupOutput.inputs["Geometry"])
```

[image]

Comment: interesting. maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Under the hood there are as many "Value" outputs as there are types of output (Boolean, integer, float, ...), they are dynamically swaped and displayed/ hidden when you changed the type dropdown. so I would not use the name to address the output of the random value node. Instead you can derive the socket number by hovering over it with the developer tooltips options enabled, which will display its data path. Or you can find it empirically by trying socket 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the explaination. I did have the developer tooltips on; but were not able to infer the correct data path. I change the line to

gnTree.links.new(gn_randomValue.outputs[3], gn_extrudeMesh.inputs["Selection"])

based on trial-and-error. It worked now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Shung-Ching can you kindly post as answer so we can close this thread? :)

Comment: I wanted to select @Gorgious's comment as answer and close the thread 2 days ago. Just don't know how. Please help